# jQuery multiselect another multiselect automatically

Tags: jquery, listbox, multi-select

I have 2 listboxfors.  When I make a selection in the first listboxfor I need it to automatically select the corresponding option in subsequent listboxfors.  If I select individual items(children) I get the result I need.  The issue I am having is if I select both items(children) I am not getting both items selected in the subsequent listboxfors.  Below are my listboxfors.

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.MajorMultiSelects,
                    new MultiSelectList(Model.Majors, "Code", "Name"),
                    new { style = "/*display:block;*/" })

@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.MultiSelectMajorGpas,
                    new MultiSelectList(Model.MajorGpas, "Code", "Name"),
                    new { style = "/*display:block;*/" })
```

Below is the jquery I am using to make the selections.

```
$("#MajorMultiSelects").change(function() {
    console.log("change");//MultiSelectMajorGpas

    if ($('#MajorMultiSelects option:nth-child(1)').is(":selected")) {
        console.log("1");
        $("#MultiSelectMajorGpas option:eq(0)").prop("selected", true);
        $("#MultiSelectMajorGpas option:eq(1)").prop("selected", false);
    }
    else if ($('#MajorMultiSelects option:nth-child(2)').is(":selected")) {
        console.log("2");
        $("#MultiSelectMajorGpas option:eq(0)").prop("selected", false);
        $("#MultiSelectMajorGpas option:eq(1)").prop("selected", true);
    } 
    //else if ($('#MajorMultiSelects option:nth-child(1)').is(":selected") && $('#MajorMultiSelects option:nth-child(2)').is(":selected")) {//This works opposite of what I need.  If both items are not selected in listboxfor 1 then items in listboxfor 2 are both selected which is not what I want.
    //    console.log("1 & 2");
    //    $("#MultiSelectMajorGpas option:eq(0)").prop("selected", true);
    //    $("#MultiSelectMajorGpas option:eq(1)").prop("selected", true);
    //}
    //else {//This doesn't work at all.
    //    $("#MultiSelectMajorGpas option:eq(0)").prop("selected", true);
    //    $("#MultiSelectMajorGpas option:eq(1)").prop("selected", true);
    //}
});
```

My listboxfors look like:

```
<select multiple id="MajorMultiSelects">
<option value="Criminal Justice">Criminal Justice</option>
<option value="Computer Science">Computer Science</option>
</select>

<select multiple id="MultiSelectMajorGpas">
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="3.45">3.45</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .val() of a select returns an array of selected values (in case multiple were selected) so all you need is to assign the value of parent select to the value of child select like this:

```
$("#MajorMultiSelects").change(function() {
  let i = 0;
  $(this).find('option').each(function() {    
    $('#MultiSelectMajorGpas option:eq('+i+')').prop("selected", $(this).is(':selected'));    
    i++;
  });
});
```

[Here is an updated example fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/5f81xjwn/)

Comment: That did not work for me.  I added an example of what the listboxfors could potentially contain.

Comment: You have completely different values and texts on both select-boxes and really want to match the index (not text, not value). I will update the answer shortly.

Comment: I have updated my answer and the fiddle based on your feedback and test case.